# what has priotity, overloaded operator or static function?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

How do I know what will be executed, operator() or static function. Although I thought that static can only stay in class, what is this static modifier doing?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
private:
    int i;
public:
    A(int ii) { i = ii; }
    int dohvati() { return i; }
    int operator()() { return 3; }
};
static int a() { return 4; }

int main() {
    A a(2);
    cout << a();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406800/when-should-i-write-the-keyword-static-before-a-non-member-function) out to see what static non-class functions are. As far as your code goes, I think that the scope is playing the main role here. Instance `a` of class `A` is in the current scope so it is chosen over method `a()` which is in the global scope.